# How can I enable touch slide on an HTML Element using CSS3 Hover transition/transform effects?

Tags: jquery, html, css, touch

I want to enable touch on a mobile device and carry the same effect (or something similar) then it's hover state on an HTML element.

I have an image that on hover, a CSS3 transition of transformX() is applied. I want to achieve the same thing with mobile but just simply by slide to the left (or tapping it).

Is this possible with CSS3/HTML? If not, which particular jQuery touch library do you recommend using?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gT47d/12/

HTML

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="slide transform multi">
<img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/fruits-vege-stock-photos/highres/orange-stock04.jpg" />

<div class="info">Fruit Info</div>  
</a>
```

CSS

```
a.slide{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.transform {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.info{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 10px; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.transform img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.transform:hover img {
    transform: translateX(90%);
    opacity: .4;
}
.multi{
    background: url(http://media02.hongkiat.com/fruits-vege-stock-photos/highres/fruitsvege-stock37.jpg); 
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gT47d/15/)**

Taping once can be achieved by using `:focus` trick.
I also moved image out side the anchor so that taping does not open the link.

HTML:

```
<div class="slide transform multi">
    <img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/fruits-vege-stock-photos/highres/orange-stock04.jpg" />
    <a href="http://google.com" class="">
        <div class="info">Fruit Info</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.transform {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: auto;
}
.info{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 10px; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.transform img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.transform:hover img, .transform:focus img, .transform img:focus {
  transform: translateX(90%);
    opacity: .4;
}
.multi{background: url(http://media02.hongkiat.com/fruits-vege-stock-photos/highres/fruitsvege-stock37.jpg); background-size:cover}
```

Comment: Thank You @Imran Bughio. Not quite what I'm looking for though. Doesn't work when testing on the iPhone/iPad.